# Corona SDK Boolean Value Multiple Lua File

Tags: file, lua, coronasdk

i am new on programming with LUA. i have a problem with multiple lua files. i wanna call a function another lua file but it doesnt. it says boolean value. thanks for your helps. here is code:

Main Lua:

```
local centerX = display.contentCenterX
local centerY = display.contentCenterY
local _W = display.contentWidth
local _H = display.contentHeight

local background = display.newImage( "facebook_bkg.png", centerX, centerY, true )

local face =require("face")

local postphoto = face.postphoto    

facebutton = display.newImageRect("fbButton184.png",247,46)
    facebutton.anchorX = 0.5
    facebutton.anchorY = 1
    facebutton:scale(3,3)
    facebutton.x = display.contentCenterX
    facebutton.y = display.contentCenterY 


facebutton:addEventListener("touch", postphoto)
```

Face Lua:

```
function postphoto (event)

    display.newText ("12313", centerX,centerY,native.systemFont, 50)

    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's `Lua`, not `LUA`. Doing this is akin to walking into a Microsoft convention with Apple products. (Jokes aside, [Lua is not an acronym](http://www.lua.org/about.html) (at 'What's in a name?), really!)

On to your code: In the main.lua file, you're defining `local` variables. These cannot be seen by anything in the face.lua file (`centerX`, `centerY`)

You're also defining postphoto as a global in face.lua, then after you require it, you define a local postphoto.

Try this in face.lua:

```
local Face = {}

function Face.postphoto (event)
  display.newText ("12313", centerX,centerY,native.systemFont, 50)
end

return Face
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. it works. thanks again for your warning about Lua name. i got it.

Comment: @user3352895 No problem. Grab a copy of Programming in Lua if you haven't already, it'll teach you the basics of Lua :) (The first edition for lua 5.0 is here: http://www.lua.org/pil/ -- the second edition is for Lua 5.1 (most commonly used, and in Corona as well), and third for Lua 5.2). As for the naming correction, I really don't like being that guy that corrects you, but better now than later.